# html to pdf download in angular jspdf

Tags: jspdf

I've installed jspdf for angular . I have some html contents to be displayed in modal and I need to download in pdf. whenever I download I get empty pdf file downloaded.

```
downloadPdf(): void {
const data = document.getElementById('pdfData');
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
  const imgWidth = 150;
  const pageHeight = 200;
  const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
  const heightLeft = imgHeight;
  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  const position = 0;
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  pdf.save('invoice.pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jspdf.html() method instead http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html.